# Function overloads and inherited types are not calling the correct overload

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following base class:

```
struct ValueType {
    String
    ToString(String const& format) const;
};
```

I want this overload to be called for types deriving from `ValueType`:

```
String FormatValue(const ValueType& value, const String& format)
{
    return value.ToString(format);
}
```

Otherwise, I want this overload to be called:

```
template <typename T>
String FormatValue(const T& value, const String& format);
```

How can I ensure that derived types do not instead call the second overload?

The [original question is located here](http://codebot.org/format-help.txt).

Comment: *Any reason at all* that you don't just use the existing practice of IOstreams for all classes? And take my advice: Coding Java or C# in C++ is a friggin *bad* idea.

Comment: I *seriously* trimmed down your question to what I think is really the core of it. While it was originally well-written, I don't think all this information was very relevant to your problem. You can rollback to your original version if you think this is wrong.

Comment: The original question can still be viewed through the edit history by clicking on the time of the last edit, no need to save it elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not too fond of what you are trying to do for different reasons (including the `ValueType` interface, why not use `AnyToString` always?), but at any rate you should be able to solve your problem with SFINAE

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if< !is_base_of<ValueType, T>::value, String>::type
FormatValue( T const & value, const String& format ) { ... }
```

What that code does (once you make it compile :) is inhibiting the template function when the condition is met. When the compiler considers the template as an overload it will try to substitute the type, and the `enable_if` instantiation will fail to have a nested `type` if the condition is met, so the substitution fails and the template is discarded. After that, the best overload will be the version that takes a `ValueType` object.

Comment: @J.N.: This question has been here for 15 minutes. :P David answered 3 mins ago. Slowpoke!

Comment: You'll need to use boost in your answer, (I don't think there's an `std::disable_if`).

Comment: @Xeo and I'm typing on an iPad, how much more advantage do you need?

Comment: @DavidR What I am trying to accomplish is to allow for custom formatting and padding syntax for example .. Format("Total is: {0:,$ #.##|-20}", amount) would convert amount into double into a thousand separated string having two decimal places and left padded to at least 20 characters. Any type which can define its own custom formatting arguments.

Comment: @J.N. I noticed, and turned that into `enable_if`.

Comment: The text after that still shows `disable_if`, so I fixed that. @sysrpl, [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-10-of-10)'s the (my) standard link to learning SFINAE.

Comment: One the line "typename enable_if< !is_base_of<ValueType, T>::value, String>::type" i get the error 'type' : is not a member of '`global namespace'. I guess I have to #include something?

Comment: @sysrpl: `<type_traits>` if your compiler supports C++11, `<boost/type_traits.hpp>` otherwise.

Comment: `enable_if` and `is_base_of` are defined in `type_traits` in C++11. If your compiler does not have C++11 support you can use boost or define the traits yourself (not too hard, but might be a bit over your level now)